# How to auto upload my text files as pages to my wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, web

So I have around 500+ text files which are my college notes.

I want to know how I can auto upload these text files as pages to my wordpress site without me getting involved in the upload process.

As in, is there any tool or plugin to create pages automatically using only my text files?

Comment: If your source are .txt files i guess the only chance you have is to write a custom plugin that reads them and create new pages with the content

Comment: @diego - you are right - there is also another ( might be simpler ) way and that is to just inject them directly into the DB without a plugin but just a simple SQL or combined script.